# Laravel custom validation attribute names with wildcards

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, wildcard

When customising Laravel 5.7 validation attributes, is it possible to include wildcards in the attribute names? I can't determine the correct way to indicate a wildcard here.

I have a contacts page which lists the details of a particular contact including all of their phone numbers and emails. From this page you can edit each of these, and add new ones. As such I've used a foreach statement to display each of these and included their id numbers in the form field names, ie:

- phone_areacode_{{ $number->id }}
- phone_number_{{ $number->id }}
- phone_extension_{{ $number->id }}

This makes their names unique and means I can display the error messages relevant only to the specific number or email being edited when validation fails. However, the error messages that display include the number so I get things like "The phone areacode 10 format is invalid." or "The phone number 27 may not be greater than 20 characters."

Is there a way to use wildcards in the attribute names when defining them in the validation language file? Basically I'd like to be able to do this:

```
'attributes' => [
  'phone_areacode_*.*' => 'phone areacode',
],
```

If not, how can I define the attribute names in the @update method of my controller?

Comment: Any solution yet?

Answer (score 2):

Post values using **arrays/objects**, and specify validation rules/lang using **dot notation**:

### Example POST data:

```
{
  "phone": {
    "ID1234": {
      "areacode": "123",
      "number": "1231234",
      "extension": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

### Example HTML form (equivalent to POST data above):

```
<form action="?" method="post">
  <input name="phone[ID1234][areacode]" />
  <input name="phone[ID1234][number]" />
  <input name="phone[ID1234][extension]" />

  <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

### Example validation:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'phone.*.areacode': 'required',
  'phone.*.number': 'required',
  'phone.*.extension': 'required',
]);
```

### Example lang file:

```
return [
  'attributes' => [
    'phone.*.areacode': 'phone area code',
    'phone.*.number': 'phone number',
    'phone.*.extension': 'phone extension',
  ],
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

do you try this way it's from Laravel documentation

```
'custom' => [
        'attribute-name' => [
            'rule-name' => 'custom-message',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: That won't work either; its the same problem I'm already having.
Where it reads 'attribute-name', I need THAT to contain the wildcard (eg. 'attribute-name_%')